# Add multiple values in input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add multiple input values in an input field with jQuery. So that everytime I hit the button, a new value is added in the same field along with the old value.

I am trying following code, but it does not add the value, it simply overwrites the previous value.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <button>Add value</button>
    <input name="myinput[]" value="" />
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('input[name=myinput\\[\\]]').val("value+");   
});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/D97bV/

Comment: Please care to explain what do you really want to "add" into "what value"? It's not working because you are setting a static value "value+"

Comment: @Kampai i just used a static value in above example. Idea is to pass multiple strings in a hidden input field to store in db. I got the answers below but thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You add strings together with `+`

```
$("button").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var elem = $(this).parent().find('input[name=myinput\\[\\]]');

    elem.val( elem.val() + 'add this' );
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/D97bV/3/)

Now you only need something useful to add ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var val = $(this).parent().find('input[name=myinput\\[\\]]').val();
    $(this).parent().find('input[name=myinput\\[\\]]').val(val+"value+");

});
```

**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/D97bV/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$("button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myInput = $(this).parent().find('input[name=myinput\\[\\]]');
    myInput.val(myInput.val() + "value+");   
});
```